# 文字列から完全に一致するテキストにリンクを追加したい

Tags: javascript, jquery

文字列から完全に一致するテキストの色を変えたいのですがどのようにすれば良いでしょうか？JQuery初心者なので教えていただけると本当に助かります。よろしくお願いします。

リンクを追加したいテキスト：`111`
文字列：`111, 112, 113`

```
var searchTxt = '111';
var addLink = $(this).text().split(",");
$.each(txt,function(i){
    var txtTrim = txt[i].replace(/\s/g, '');
    if(txtTrim==searchTxt){
        txtTrim.css( "color", "red" );
    }
});
```

Comment: 「リンクを作成する」のと「テキストの色を変える」といのは区別した方がよろしいかと思います。

Comment: 後、明確化のために、`<div class="doc">Text</div>`のような特定のタグの中のテキストであるとか、ネストしている`<div class="doc"><p>Text</p></div>`ネストの一部である`<div class="doc">Text<p>Other</p></div>`一致するテキストが一部タグで修飾されている`<div class="doc">Search<b>Text</b></div>`(`SearchText`で一致したい)など具体的な例を挙げられると(考慮すべき事項が異なるので)いいかと思います。